# ActiveRecord: Retrieve all records where updated_at is 24 hours or more after created_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I try to find all records that were updated (`updated_at`) at least 24 hours or more after its creation (`created_at`) using ActiveRecord and a Postgres db.

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: Call like `Model.where("updated_at >= (created_at + interval '1' day)")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give a more explicit condition by checking the condition using the `hours` directly,

`Model.where("updated_at >= created_at + interval '24' hour")`

returns the query,

`SELECT`models`.* FROM`models`WHERE (updated_at >= (created_at + interval '22' hour))`

Checked this query and its working fine for my models, hope works for you too,

Answer (score 0):

You can write a scope for this

```
scope :scope_name , -> () { where("updated_at::date > created_at::date") }
```

Comment: Where in the code `at least one day after its creation` ? :)

Comment: Dude i have used the greater than sign so date will only be greater if it is one day after created at. Hope it makes sense. Thanks

Comment: Why both queries return different results then?

Comment: i have provided you only one single query.

Comment: @FakhirShad It is not about single query, you are by passing the time part, which with all proper edge case data will give wrong result.

Comment: Actually this does not return the same result than Arup answer.

Comment: yes time isn't required here as the comparison should be made explicitly on the basis of date. You will get accurate result with my query as i m doing comparison in exact dates rather than time. Run a test case on this.

Comment: How could the query be further improved then to at least 24 hours difference? Gonna update the question, sorry.

Comment: @FakhirShad No, it is not. I don't know if I am missing, or why you are not getting. The query you wrote wouldn't have exact 24 hours or 1 day difference. A record created at "01/08/2016 11:59 PM" and updated at "02/08/2016 12:01 AM" is not what should be present in the result.

Comment: If this is used in more than 1 place in your app, it is a good practice to use scopes.

Comment: why are people upvoting this answer?

Comment: @SriramR This is not about _scope_. It is all about wrong logic.

Comment: @Martin I am also wondering the same thing.. and I have no clue. What is going on.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by using following query

```
Model.where("updated_at > (Date(created_at) + integer '1')")
```

Here is [reference](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html)